# Парсинг строки php

Tags: php, yii2

Как из master-at-home сделать masterathome?
Напишите пример выражения.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$str = 'master-at-home';


echo str_replace( '-', '', $str ) . "\n";


echo $str . "\n";


echo preg_replace( '=\-=', '', $str );
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cbebba223e42deb87259c6dab7ec1639d99469c

Comment: Казалось бы, чем плоха str_replace()?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ничем — кто как привык и что первое на ум пришло; добавил в ответ ...